# alternative xp_cmdshell in sql azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

what is the alternative of  XP_CMDshell  ? it is working fine in sql server 
but it is not support in sql azure 
so what is alternative for sql azure ?

Comment: What do you want to do? I mean, copy a file or something else?

Comment: Make XML file into azure sql and then replace into c drive or some where in physical location from sql azure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you need command line access to access BCP since you are trying to create and upload/download data into a flat or xml file.

SQL Azure does not provide access to a command prompt.  Think of SQL Azure as just a virtualized service, without host infrastructure (Virtualized or physical).  Since BCP is actually a command line based utility you won't have access to it from Azure.  You'll want to setup BCP, which is part of the command line utilities, on a machine that does have access to command line.  That machine might be either on-premise or Azure IaaS.  You can install just the BCP component.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36433

Alternatively if you don't want to setup physical infrastructure to complete this, Azure Data Factory would be able to complete the task of moving data between flat files and databases.