# Alternative to xp_cmdshell in Azure SQL Managed Instance to rename files?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

One of my developers was asking me to enable xp_cmdshell in our on-premises SQL server so she could test renaming files from SQL Server stored procedure. Since xp_cmdshell is not supported in Azure SQL Managed Instance (and it looks like a security risk) I told her I would not enable that for use. However, I am trying to find an alternative for this developer to go about what she was trying to do.

Does anyone know of a viable alternative to using xp_cmdshell for the purpose of renaming files in Azure SQL Managed Instance? The only thing I can think of is maybe running PowerShell in SQL Agent as a job, but wondering what other people would suggest.

Thank you in advance for all help!

Comment: I would use PS if it was on-prem. Does Azure MI even have a filesystem?

Comment: The entire approach is faulty - you should not be using the database engine to manage things in the file system. This is typically a kludge to avoid writing more robust ETL logic IME.

Comment: Azure MI doesn't have a file system, but I think you could use Powershell in the SQL Agent to manipulate files on a Windows VM for example.

Comment: Hi @Pablo, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I searched and per my experience, there isn't a equivalent of XP_CMDSHELL in Azure SQL managed instance.

SQL Azure does not provide access to a command prompt. Think of SQL Azure as just a virtualized service, without host infrastructure (Virtualized or physical).

Azure SQLDB does not support xp_cmdshell. Full stop. There is no "equivalent" because Azure SQLDB runs in a shared environment without access to the host unlike the standalone, full access to the host environment you're used to with your on-premises instances.

As you said, if you could use Powershell in the SQL Agent to manipulate files on a Windows VM for example, that's could be good way.

Ref:

1. [Equivalent of XP_CMDSHELL in AzureDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836220/equivalent-of-xp-cmdshell-in-azuredb)
2. [alternative xp_cmdshell in sql azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407800/alternative-xp-cmdshell-in-sql-azure)

HTH.